# Image Browse Option does not shown in Tinymce / FCK editor

Tags: php, jquery, html, tinymce, fckeditor

I downloaded Tinymce text editor from http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download/download.php  -- TinyMCE 3.4.2 , in it's Demo there is an option to **Browse Image** but after download and test it doesn't have any **Image Browse** option. I searched in the code to set this option but fail.

And same thing was happening in FCK editor.

Any help..

Comment: thats called ajax file browser(manager), thats not free :( , i guess you have to buy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "insert image" and "insert file" toolbar buttons in the [TinyMCE Full Demo](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php) are actually provided by two of MoxieCodes commercial plugins, [MCImageManager](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/enterprise/mcimagemanager.php) and [MCFileManager](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/enterprise/mcfilemanager.php).

I can't comment on similar functionality within CKEditor as I've not used it.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to upload files (and images) you need to download a third party plugin.

Here's a nice tutorial in how to manage that with step by step configuration:

http://pascal.vanhecke.info/2005/08/25/image-upload-plugin-for-tinymce/

Comment: I searched "tinyMCE.init" in whole folder and script but did not found except readme.txt file(located at F:\xampp\htdocs\tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce\plugins\ibrowser\docs). Can you help where does this statement exists?

Comment: tinyMCE.init is not a file. Is the statement to initialize the Tiny MCE Toolbar. It should be as javascript in the file you want it to display.